# How can I find the maximum value of $x_6-x_1$ subject to the two constraints $\sum_{j=1}^{6} x_j^2$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{6} x_j = 0$

Tags: optimization

I currently have six variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6$. I am trying to determine how large I can make the difference $x_6-x_1$ while satisfying the constraints:

$\sum_{j=1}^{6} x_j^2 \leq 1$

$\sum_{j=1}^{6} x_j = 0$

So far I have tried to use an optimization package in R but to no avail. Is there a way I can program this out or would it be too much to handle? Thanks!

Comment: What's the constraint? That those two sums are equal to specific number?   0?  (If it's 0,  it seems pretty meaningless, since then all the squares would have to be 0)...

Comment: @Alan sorry, fixed my question!

Comment: You can solve this by inspection, what do you need an optimization package for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
(x_6-x_1)^2\leq 2(x_6^2+x_1^2)\le2
$$
with all inequalities becoming equalities when $x_6=\pm1/\sqrt{2}$ and $x_1=-x_6$. Thus,
$$
\max(x_6-x_1)=\sqrt{2}
$$
which realizes when $x_1=-1/\sqrt{2}$, $x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=0$, and $x_6=1/\sqrt{2}$.